# Melpa packages aren't being added

Tags: package, use-package

I have this in my `init.el`

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)

;;; Remove SC if you are not using sunrise commander and org if you like outdated packages
(setq package-archives '(("ELPA"  . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
                         ("gnu"   . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("org"   . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")))

(package-initialize)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;; Bootstrapping use-package
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
```

Then this lower down inside of `custom-set-variables`:

```
'(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (org-ref techela tuareg haskell-mode gnuplot gnuplot-mode helm-ispell ac-ispell paredit ox-tufte auctex json org-grep iedit wgrep helm geiser slime-company company-jedi zzz-to-char rainbow-delimiters avy ivy projectile twittering-mode zerodark-theme pretty-mode flycheck-clang-analyzer flycheck-irony flycheck yasnippet company-c-headers company-shell company-irony irony irony-mode company-lua mark-multiple expand-region popup-kill-ring dmenu ido-vertical-mode ido-vertical ox-html5slide centered-window-mode htmlize ox-twbs diminish erc-hl-nicks symon rainbow-mode switch-window dashboard smex company sudo-edit emms magit org-bullets hungry-delete beacon linum-relative spaceline fancy-battery exwm use-package)))
```

My problem is when I clear out everything from my `.emacs.d/` but the `init.el` which calls `config.org` which does lots of configurations, (i.e., I'm forcing a complete reinstall of everything package-wise) I get errors such as

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "ox-tufte")
  require(ox-tufte)
  eval((require 'ox-tufte) nil)
```

That is, in my `config.org` a call is made, `(require 'ox-tufte)` and the error above happens. A clean startup (no existing `elpa` directory) should go and get `ox-tufte` should it not? It's included in the `package-selected-packages` list. My understanding is that this

```
;;; Bootstrapping use-package
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
```

ensures anything listed in the `package-selected-packages` if not found, will be gotten from melpa etc. and setup. But then I don't see org-mode (latest from repo) specifically listed anywhere either. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The code you quote only does what the comment says, i.e. "Bootstrapping use-package".  If you want to install the selected packages, you have to do that explicitly by calling `package-install-selected-packages`.

Comment: So how do I say to Emacs, "I want all the package names you see in the `package-selected-packages` list installed if they're not already?

Comment: @147pm: "by calling `package-install-selected-packages`"?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `use-package`, you need not `require` packages. Instead, you might write:

```
(use-package ox-tufte
  :ensure t)
```

In this case, `:ensure t` will make sure that, if the package is not found on your system, it will search your `package-archives` for the package and install it to your system.

To avoid having to write `:ensure t` for each package you want to ensure is installed, you could `(setq use-package-always-ensure t)`. If you set this variable to `t`, you still would need to use `(use-package ox-tufte)`, you just wouldn't have to include `:ensure t` for every occurrence of `(use-package [package-name])`.

For example:

```
(use-package some-package
  :ensure t)

(use-package another-package
  :ensure t)

(use-package some-other-package
  :ensure t)
```

The previous code could be shortened with the following code:

```
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

(use-package some-package)

(use-package another-package)

(use-package some-other-package)
```

---

In regard to having up-to-date packages, you could add this to your configuration:

```
(setq load-prefer-newer t)
```

Comment: The `(setq use-package-always-ensure t)` didn't seem to work, but the individual `use-package...` did. BTW, my other question "How is latest org-mode being installed?" is still puzzling me. My version according to `org-version` is `Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542` which seems out of date. So like `ox-tufte` how do I tell Emacs to get the latest from the org-mode repo if it's not already installed?

Comment: `(setq use-package-always-ensure t)`, I believe, should be near the top of your config file, above all occurrences of `use-package` (except, of course, for the installation of `use-package` itself - which is what your bootstrap is doing).

Comment: `org-mode` comes built-in to emacs now. I'm not sure which version of emacs that started in, however, as I'm pretty new to Emacs (I started with 26.1)

Comment: Edited my answer to include keeping packages up-to-date (bottom of my answer)